# How many possible Venn diagrams are there for given cardinalities of the sets?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Consider $n$ non-empty finite sets with cardinalities $c_1$, $\ldots$, $c_n$. How many possibilities are there for the Venn diagram of these sets? (I'm surprised I didn't find the answer with Google).

---

## Edit

It seems the Venn diagrams are in bijection with the partitions of the multiset $\{\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{c_1},\dots,\underbrace{n,n,\dots,n}_{c_n}\}$ into sets. This has been noted in a comment by @Ilya Bogdanov. And this is confirmed in some cases. For example when $c_1=2$, $c_2=1$ and $c_3=1$, there are $6$ Venn diagrams, and there are $6$ partitions of $\{1,1,2,3\}$:

```
 1:    { 1 }{ 1 2 3 }
 2:    { 1 2 }{ 1 3 }
 3:    { 1 }{ 1 }{ 2 3 }
 4:    { 1 }{ 2 }{ 1 3 }
 5:    { 1 }{ 3 }{ 1 2 }
 6:    { 1 }{ 1 }{ 2 }{ 3 }
```

Comment: Which "Vien diagrams" you consider as equal?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I consider a Venn diagram is given by a partition, e.g. for two sets $A$ and $B$ the partition is $A\cap B$, $A\cap B^c$, $A^c \cap B$. Then two Venn diagrams for $A$ and $B$ are equal if there are the same number of elements in each part. Makes sense?

Comment: (I suspect the answer is related to multiset partitions)

Comment: In what terms do you want this number to be expressed?

Comment: @IosifPinelis in a way that can be implemented in a programming language

Comment: There are $2^n$ regions of a Venn diagram with $n$ sets, and $2^n-1$ if we throw out the "outer" region. You are asking for the number of ways to assign nonnegative integers to these regions, so that the sum of the values assigned to certain regions (those corresponding to the sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$) sum to the given values $c_1,\ldots,c_n$. So it should be pretty clear that one can write a computer program which computes all these possibilities, say by brute force. Of course, you might be interested in an efficient program, or better yet a useful formula.

Comment: @SamHopkins I already wrote a program that enumerates all possibilities. Now I'd like a formula for the count, without enumerating.

Comment: Am I right that those are in an obvious bijection with the partitions of the multiset $\{\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{c_1},\dots,\underbrace{n,n,\dots,n}_{c_n}\}$ into *sets* (each part corresponds to one element)? If so, it is easy to write down some Stirling-like relations for those numbers (perhaps, with a fixed number of parts).

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov That looks true (see my edit).